# Uninstalling Ultimo Infortis theme Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ultimo, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall a theme (Ultimo) from my M2 store.

Am I on the right track?

- Should I remove both ultimo contents in app/design and app/code?
- Remove database data from table "theme", I found "Infortis/base" and "Infortis/ultimo" entry.
- Clean and flush.
- Done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are on right track. Just make sure you are deleting theme in database properly,

refer [magento's official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-uninstall.html#uninstall-a-manually-added-theme)

Answer (score 2):

I've uninstalled Ultimo Theme from magento 2 after reading the end of the support. Here is what i did :

- Delete app/code/Infortis
- Delete app/design/frontend/Infortis
- Kept the pub/media/wysiwyg/Infortis in order to keep the seo for the images on google.

On ssh : 
php bin/magento module:disable Infortis_Infortis
php bin/magento module:disable Infortis_Brands
php bin/magento module:disable Infortis_Cgen
php bin/magento module:disable Infortis_Dataporter
php bin/magento module:disable Infortis_Base
php bin/magento module:disable Infortis_UltraSlideshow
php bin/magento module:disable Infortis_UltraMegamenu
php bin/magento module:disable Infortis_Ultimo

rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/

*rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/

*rm -rf var/generation/*
rm -rf var/cache/

*rm -rf var/di/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Database :

- Delete Infortis/base and Infortis/Ultimo  from "theme" table.
- Delete every Infortis entry from "catalog_category_entity_text" table
- Delete every umm_ entry from "eav_attribut" table
- Delete every Infortis entry from "core_config_date" table
- Delete every ultramegamenu from "core_config_date" table
- Delete every ultraslideshow from "core_config_date" table
- Delete every Infortis from "authorization _rule" table
- Delete Infortis from "theme" table
- Delete Ultramegamenu from "theme" table

I still have an error from an featuredlist of ultimo that gets called on the luma theme. Here is the code :

```
[2020-09-17 12:25:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Infortis\Base\Block\Product\ProductList\Featured {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): Invalid block type: Infortis\\Base\\Block\\Product\\ProductList\\Featured at /chroot/home/webiste_url/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:278, ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Infortis\\Base\\Block\\Product\\ProductList\\Featured does not exist at /chroot/home/webiste_url/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:26)"} []
```

Hope this helps people knowing how many are on ultimo and want to change because they stopped support on it.

Rgds,
Marc

Comment: This is great, does someone know how to delete the database tables in a single query? I have to do this allot when importing databases.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to Infortis Ultimo removal in Magento 2, I did the following (slightly different from Marcwales's answer my goal is to remove it entirely not to disable anything), probably a bit over but this worked step by step, I was uninstalling Ultimo from Magento 2.3.6-p1 and this is all before touching a new theme installation:

**do this on a test / dev server site copy first, not your live site!**
I disabled Crons and popped my dev copy site in maintenance mode to avoid crons running errors which would happen during this process:

Set Theme in Magento back to Luma (Content>Design>Configuration), and then
via ssh to clear everything to be sure:

```
rm -rf generated/metadata/* generated/code/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
rm -rf pub/static/*
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (or your store language options)
```

*nb: observe, no deployment of ultimo theme.*

Clear/Flush Cache

In Magento admin, remove any code on the home page, other pages / widgets / static blocks involving Infortis extension code and just delete the static blocks specific to Infortis (i.e slideshows, you'll need to start afresh in new theme anyway for those most likely!).

via ssh delete the following directories and all contents:

```
app\code\Infortis
app\design\frontend\Infortis
```

*(ideally just leave "pub\media\wysiwyg\infortis" alone, it's not massive, agreed SEO reasons for this)*

Run the following commands:

```
rm -rf generated/metadata/* generated/code/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
rm -rf pub/static/*
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Clear/Flush Cache

You should find your front end working but product images may be missing, this is because of changing themes & image specs, you'll need to re-generate the images for your entire website. Don't bother with this if you are installing a new theme because you'll just need to do it all over again at that point. Just check your pages for errors calling Infortis extensions, these are likely page content, static blocks or widgets and just disable / remove or amend as needed.

Database clean up (this is a lot of rows give an hour or so for this careful work, compiled list after some analysis):

```
Delete rows for Infortis/base and Infortis/Ultimo from the "theme" table
Delete every row containing Infortis from the "authorization_rule" table
Delete every umm_ entry row from the "eav_attribut" table
Delete every row with path starting "theme_settings" from the "core_config_data" table
Delete every row with path starting "theme_design" from the "core_config_data" table
Delete every row with path starting "theme_layout" from the "core_config_data" table
Delete every row with path starting "ultraslideshow" from the "core_config_data" table
Delete every row with path starting "ultramegamenu" from the "core_config_data" table
Delete every row with Infortis referenced from "setup_module" table.
```

At this stage, if you do a search on your entire database for "Infortis", you may find some static blocks or page content has references to Infortis, don't change that here, you need to clean that up via the backend, just note them for reference / to-do's later on.

Ignore any search results for logs, but note any tables related to optimization extensions you may have, any optimization extensions need to be cleared and re-set including any cache extensions.

Run the following:

```
rm -rf generated/metadata/* generated/code/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
rm -rf pub/static/*
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:clean && bin/magento cache:flush && bin/magento cache:enable
```

Check admin, from the notes on your database cleanup review pages, static blocks, widgets and any optimization extensions. It's worth switching Magento to dev mode just to double check there are no bugs/errors showing there front end of the site.

You should find now the only thing not working is product images but generally everything else works. Images are straight forward to regenerate, from admin back end cache, delete all generated image files and run the following in ssh:

bin/magento catalog:image:resize

But with big stores the above is time consuming. If you are installing and configuring a new template just go ahead with that first to avoid having to generate the images all over again.

I hope this helps - exhausting!

Comment: Additional comment:
If you get an error trying to edit categories or products such as "unable to load specified theme by key 5", search path "design/theme/theme_id" in your core_config_data table and find that row, delete it or update the value to Luma for example which by default is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @jamie-dijstra his answer:

Create backup from your database and do it first on a staging environment before you do on production site.

MySQL Query

```
DELETE FROM `theme` 
WHERE `theme_path` 
LIKE '%Infortis%';

DELETE FROM `authorization_rule` 
WHERE `resource_id`
LIKE '%Infortis%';

DELETE FROM `eav_attribute`
WHERE `attribute_code`
LIKE '%umm_%'; 

DELETE FROM `core_config_data` 
WHERE `path` 
LIKE '%theme_settings%';

DELETE FROM `core_config_data` 
WHERE `path` 
LIKE '%theme_design%';

DELETE FROM `core_config_data` 
WHERE `path` 
LIKE '%theme_layout%';

DELETE FROM `core_config_data` 
WHERE `path` 
LIKE '%ultraslideshow%';

DELETE FROM `core_config_data` 
WHERE `path` 
LIKE '%ultramegamenu%';

DELETE FROM `setup_module`
WHERE `module`
LIKE '%Infortis%';
```

My customer also had a lot of categories with a "custom_design" (attribute_id 60 & 100 in my case) en these gave an error:
Some categories had also the Luma theme as custom_design, so I decided all the rows that have a "custom_design" added, delete the value in `catalog_category_entity_varchar` where `attribute_id` = `60` & `100`